# Add maven-build-classpath to plugin execution classpath

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I am writing some code-gen maven-plugin.

I need my project classpath be injected in to my plugin execution classpath.

I found this [article](https://webtide.com/extending-the-maven-plugin-classpath-at-runtime/). The solution there works but is quite long. Maybe someone of you know an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 22):

Found the [answer](http://old.nabble.com/Adding-project-dependencies-and-generated-classes-to-classpath-of-my-plugin-td18624435.html)!

OK , Pascal is right , here it is for the foundation!!

So here is the cleanest way ( as far as i know ) to add the compile classpath to the execution of you plugin.

Here are some code samples from my code-gen plugin, that is actually generating some template code based on the code compiled. So I needed first the code compiled, then analyzed, generate some code, and then compiled again.

1. Use `@configurator` in the Mojo class:

   ```
   /**
    * @goal generate
    * @phase process-classes
    * @configurator include-project-dependencies
    * @requiresDependencyResolution compile+runtime
    */
   public class CodeGenMojo
           extends AbstractMojo
   {
       public void execute()
               throws MojoExecutionException
       {
            // do work....   
       }
   }
   ```

   Please pay attention to the `@configurator` line in the javadoc header, it is essetial for the plexus IOC container and is not just another comment line.
2. The implementation of the `include-project-dependencies` configurator. There is this very nice class that I took from some Brian Jackson, add it to the source of your plugin.

   ```
   /**
    * A custom ComponentConfigurator which adds the project's runtime classpath elements
    * to the
    *
    * @author Brian Jackson
    * @since Aug 1, 2008 3:04:17 PM
    *
    * @plexus.component role="org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurator"
    *                   role-hint="include-project-dependencies"
    * @plexus.requirement role="org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.lookup.ConverterLookup"
    *                   role-hint="default"
    */
   public class IncludeProjectDependenciesComponentConfigurator extends AbstractComponentConfigurator { 

       private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(IncludeProjectDependenciesComponentConfigurator.class);

       public void configureComponent( Object component, PlexusConfiguration configuration,
                                       ExpressionEvaluator expressionEvaluator, ClassRealm containerRealm,
                                       ConfigurationListener listener )
           throws ComponentConfigurationException {

           addProjectDependenciesToClassRealm(expressionEvaluator, containerRealm);

           converterLookup.registerConverter( new ClassRealmConverter( containerRealm ) );

           ObjectWithFieldsConverter converter = new ObjectWithFieldsConverter();

           converter.processConfiguration( converterLookup, component, containerRealm.getClassLoader(), configuration,
                                           expressionEvaluator, listener );
       }

       private void addProjectDependenciesToClassRealm(ExpressionEvaluator expressionEvaluator, ClassRealm containerRealm) throws ComponentConfigurationException {
           List<String> runtimeClasspathElements;
           try {
               //noinspection unchecked
               runtimeClasspathElements = (List<String>) expressionEvaluator.evaluate("${project.runtimeClasspathElements}");
           } catch (ExpressionEvaluationException e) {
               throw new ComponentConfigurationException("There was a problem evaluating: ${project.runtimeClasspathElements}", e);
           }

           // Add the project dependencies to the ClassRealm
           final URL[] urls = buildURLs(runtimeClasspathElements);
           for (URL url : urls) {
               containerRealm.addConstituent(url);
           }
       }

       private URL[] buildURLs(List<String> runtimeClasspathElements) throws ComponentConfigurationException {
           // Add the projects classes and dependencies
           List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>(runtimeClasspathElements.size());
           for (String element : runtimeClasspathElements) {
               try {
                   final URL url = new File(element).toURI().toURL();
                   urls.add(url);
                   if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                       LOGGER.debug("Added to project class loader: " + url);
                   }
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   throw new ComponentConfigurationException("Unable to access project dependency: " + element, e);
               }
           }

           // Add the plugin's dependencies (so Trove stuff works if Trove isn't on
           return urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]);
       }

   }
   ```
3. Here is the build part of my plugin that you will have to add.

   ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.delver</groupId>
   <artifactId>reference-gen-plugin</artifactId>
   <name>Reference Code Genration Maven Plugin</name>

   <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
   <version>1.2</version>

   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
       <maven.version>2.2.1</maven.version>
   </properties>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
               <artifactId>plexus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>descriptor</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.9</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   ```

   Here is the pom.xml of the plugin for these who need it. Should compile wihtout a problem now. ( something wrong with the header, so ignore it )

Comment: +1 Yes, that's the way to go AFAIK. It would be nice to explain or summarize the link in your answer though. That would greatly improve the value of your question and your answer for readers IMHO.

Comment: This is the solution I need too - I can't get it to compile though.
I think I have the wrong version of some of the classes.

I wonder if you could add the relevant sections of your pom.xml to your answer too please.

Comment: To make `project.runtimeClasspathElements` include all transitive dependencies, you need to annotate the mojo with [`@requiresDependencyResolution`](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations).

Comment: The `ClassRealm` used in this example is deprecated in plexus-classworlds 2.5.2.

Answer (score 21):

I took this approach and apparently it's working:

1 - a MavenProject parameter is needed within your Mojo class:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

2 - and then you can get the classpath elements from project instance:

```
try {
    Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> elements = project.getTestClasspathElements();
                                  //getRuntimeClasspathElements()
                                  //getCompileClasspathElements()
                                  //getSystemClasspathElements()  
    for (String element : elements) {
        urls.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
    }

    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
            urls.toArray(new URL[0]),
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);

} catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: +1. Instead of accessing the classpath elements through the `MavenProject` field, one can also ask for the elements to be injected immediately, e.g. `@Parameter(property = "project.compileClasspathElements", required = true, readonly = true) private List<String> classpath;`

Comment: If you're using this to scan for classes using `org.reflections.Reflections`, you'll want to instantiate `Reflections` using: `new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(contextClassLoader))`

Comment: The `@Parameter` solution mentioned by @Stephan202 worked for me. Getting them from the project did not (even with `requiresDependencyResolution` in the `@Mojo` annotation)

Answer (score 1):

followed this link.... did very similar thing for my code... i have created a maven-fit-plugin
I have used exactly the same pom.xml for my plugin, reusing the IncludeProjectDependenciesComponentConfigurator

I am using maven 2.2.0
if it can help, here's pom again

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.worldcorpservices.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-fit-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>maven-fit-plugin Maven Mojo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <fitlibrary.version>2.0</fitlibrary.version>
    <maven.version>2.2.0</maven.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fitnesse</groupId>
        <artifactId>fitlibrary</artifactId>
        <version>${fitlibrary.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7-20101029</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
```

hope this helps

rgds
 marco

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>
```