# Maven Plugin: Use Classes out of the Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

when i use a plugin, is there a way to use classes out of the plugin?

I created a maven-plugin and i want the plugin to be used when you 
have a class inheriting from a specific interface. The interface
is inside my maven-plugin.

Now i create a maven-projekt using my maven-plugin.
How can i use my interface out of the maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, projects can always have a dependency on a plugin. I mean -- they're also regular artifacts.

If I were you, I would extract the common code which could be used outside the plugin, into a separate module (artifact). This way both the plugin and the projects which need to depend on it will be neat. Even if it's for one class.

Comment: What do you think about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659048/add-maven-build-classpath-to-plugin-execution-classpath

Comment: Not a good idea to be altering the classloader yourself (although I have done this in a plugin or two). Just extract the class or two into a separate module and be done with it. Not as elegant as you would have liked, but elegant enough to do the trick for you.