# how to pass maven module classes to a maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I've developed a maven plugin, which can scan classes within a module, to find some specific classes and do something about them.

The problem is that, when I'm using this plugin in a maven module, It's not able to find classes within that module.

I've checked the plugin classpath and it only contains **plugin classes** and it's **dependencies**.

Is there any way to automatically include module classes into plugin classpath?

Comment: Would this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659048/add-maven-build-classpath-to-plugin-execution-classpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this approach and apparently it's working:

1 - a MavenProject parameter is needed within your Mojo class:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

2 - and then you can get the classpath elements from project instance:

```
try {
    Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> elements = project.getTestClasspathElements();
                                  //getRuntimeClasspathElements()
                                  //getCompileClasspathElements()
                                  //getSystemClasspathElements()  
    for (String element : elements) {
        urls.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
    }

    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
            urls.toArray(new URL[0]),
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);

} catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```