# Using maven 3, how to use project classpath in a plugin?

Tags: maven, classpath, maven-plugin

I'm writing a maven 3 plugin, for which I would like to use project classpath.

I've tried using the approach mentionned in [Add maven-build-classpath to plugin execution classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659324/15619), but it seems the written component is not found by maven. (I have a `ComponentNotFoundException` at plugin execution start).

So, what is the "reference" way to use project classpath in a maven 3 plugin ? Or if the component way is the right one, is there any configuration step beside adding the component as `configurator` property of the `@Mojo` annotation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the classpath elements on the [`MavenProject`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) by calling:

- [`getCompileClasspathElements()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getCompileClasspathElements%28%29) to retrieve the classpath formed by compile scoped dependencies
- [`getRuntimeClasspathElements()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getRuntimeClasspathElements%28%29) to retrieve the classpath formed by runtime scoped dependencies (i.e. compile + runtime)
- [`getTestClasspathElements()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getTestClasspathElements%28%29) to retrieve the classpath formed by test scoped dependencies (i.e. compile + system + provided + runtime + test)

A sample MOJO would be:

```java
@Mojo(name = "foo", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        try {
            getLog().info(project.getCompileClasspathElements().toString());
            getLog().info(project.getRuntimeClasspathElements().toString());
            getLog().info(project.getTestClasspathElements().toString());
        } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Error while determining the classpath elements", e);
        }
    }

}
```

What makes this work:

- The `MavenProject` is injected with the `@Parameter` annotation using the `${project}` property
- `requiresDependencyResolution` will enable the plugin accessing the dependencies of the project with the mentioned resolution scope.

Comment: requiresDependencyResolution has no effect. project has zip dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes having a look at the code of a plugin which does exactly the same explains it a lot better. If there's one plugin which needs to know classpaths it's the maven-compiler-plugin ([source](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.html)). Just look for `classpathElements`.