# How to use project classpath in a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have long list of dependencies in a project and a custom maven plugin.
I'd like to avoid duplication of these dependencies and access them out of the box from default class loader of the plugin.

I've found a similar [question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829762/using-maven-3-how-to-use-project-classpath-in-a-plugin), though it doesn't solve my problem.

I discovered that @Mojo has an attribute which does exactly what I want

```
requiresDependencyResolution = COMPILE
```

But there is one problem with it. It's not working.

```
  getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.json")
```

the line above returns null if plugin's dependency list is empty, while the project has the dependency.

I have a hard code workaround for this:

```
IOUtil.toString(new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
    getProject().getDependencyArtifacts().stream()
.findFirst().get().getFile().toURI().toURL() }, 

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ).getResourceAsStream("file.json"))
```

I thing there is some trick I just don't see.
My goals:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>help-goal</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

One observation I cannot explain:

in the first case getResourceAsStream only works if path prefixed with "/"
and in the second case getResourceAsStream only works if path without "/".

Comment: I do understand your approach: You try to use classes from dependencies of the _project_ in a plugin? What if the plugin is used in another project?

Comment: What is resolution scope of the dependency which you're trying to get?