# Spring: Request load properties in maven plugin project but use file from project the plugin is used in

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file

I have written maven plugin which is using spring context dependency injection.

At some point in time spring must initialize one of the beans with properties file. In tests everything works ok. But when plugin is built and used in different project as part of build process, FileNotFoundException is thrown.

When printing current classpath entries by using:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println("CLASSPATH: " + url.getFile());
}
```

only thing I get is:

```
CLASSPATH: /path/to/mavendir/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
```

And normally properties are loaded by following code:

```
Resource resource = springContext.getResource("classpath:/myPluginConfig.properties");
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

But file is not found.

I have placed correctly named file "**myPluginConfig.properties**" in **/src/main/resources/** in project which use my plugin.

During process-resources phase, file is copied to target/classes dir (I have checked it existence). So the file is there but classpath is somehow broken.

My plugin is installed only locally still as snapshot so I can quickly update it and reinstall it.

Can anyone please help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

when we use the jar in diffrent project,the resources path should like of this:       classpath*:myPluginConfig.properties

Comment: Hi. Thanks for fast reply. Sadly it is not working in my case :-( Any other possibilities?

Comment: please give me the screenshot of you jar  which use in the project as a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question is:

1. In maven plugin project **before spring context is initialized** modify classpath adding maven runtime classpath to system context classpath [original solution on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263482/1235977) and bellow my slightly modified one

This should be called my maven during mojo execution. Preferably as early as possible.

```
    private void enhanceClassloaderAndInitSpring() {
        try {
            Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<>();
            List<Stream<String>> streams = new ArrayList<>();
            streams.add(project.getRuntimeClasspathElements().stream());
            streams.add(project.getCompileClasspathElements().stream());
            streams.add(project.getSystemClasspathElements().stream());

            for (String element : streams.stream().flatMap(s -> s).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
                System.out.println("Adding element to classpath: " + element);
                urls.add(new File(element).toURI().toURL());
            }

            ClassLoader contextClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                    urls.toArray(new URL[0]),
                    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);

            // springContext is just local field in class
            springContext = initSpringContext();
        } catch (DependencyResolutionRequiredException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

2. Init spring context
3. Use java classloader or spring context to get resource but do not prefix resource string with "classpath:" (at least in my case it wasn't working)

   ```
   Resource resource = springContext.getResource("myPluginConfig.properties");
   if (!resource.exists()) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Resource does not exist and resource object pointing to nothing was created");
   }

   Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
   ```